# display odd div without image and even with images in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, if-statement

Want to hide particular odd div tag images and show even div images.like

I have

div1   div2   div3   div4
div5   div6   div7   div8
div9   div10  div11  div12

Now, I want to hide images that is on div1,div5,div9 and show only other div tags images in Wordpress using If condition or while loop.

How Do i do..

these is my code.

```
<div class="default-team">
<div class="medium-3 columns">
    <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>

    <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink();?>">Click to View Bio</a>       

</div>  
</div>


<?php  while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );   ?>

    <div class="team-inner">
        <div class="medium-3 columns">
            <div class="team-img">
                <img src="<?php echo $feat_image; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="team-hover">
                <a href="#">View Bio</a>
            </div>             
        </div>
   </div>
```

i want to hide "default-team" these div tag images and show "team-inner" these div tag images.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
Instead of it being the `nth-of-type(odd)` selector you can use the `nth-child(number)` selector, take at the code sample to see what happens with this

For more on this selector look [here](http://nthmaster.com/).

Your code would look something like this:

```
div:nth-child(4) img { /* This will select the 4th div and apply the given style to that div */
    display:none;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just want to hide 1st, 5th, 9th, 13th and rest div tags display.!
Like I want to hide image on first div tag then show next 3 div tags images then hide 5th div image and display next 3 div tag images.! got it ?

Comment: Ah, give me a moment to work that out, misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. Don't need to create any kind of loops.

```
div:nth-of-type(4n+1) img {display:none;}
div:nth-child(4n+1) img{display:none;}             ///What ever you want
```

I'm here if there is still any error.

Comment: that's exactly right, but i want to do it in php. So i need it loop.

Comment: with the same type you can make loop, '4n+1' formula :D